# Conditional JOIN Statement in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have the following, working MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
    a.id id,
    a.price price,
    a.stock stock,
    a.max_per_user max_per_user,
    a.purchased purchased, 
    b.quantity owned 
FROM 
    shop_items a 
        JOIN shop_inventory b 
            ON b.iid=a.id 
            AND b.cid=a.cid 
WHERE 
    a.cid=1 
    AND a.szbid=0 
    AND a.id IN(3,4)
```

The `JOIN` joins the table `shop_inventory b` to return `b.quantity owned`. However, if there is no record in the `shop_inventory b` table where `b.iid=a.id` I want it to return `b.quantity = 0`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead. And `COALESCE` since some of the records where null (*I guess*). Try,

```
SELECT a.id id,a.price price,a.stock stock,
       a.max_per_user max_per_user,a.purchased purchased, 
       COALESCE(b.quantity, 0) owned 
FROM shop_items a 
          LEFT JOIN shop_inventory b 
                ON b.iid=a.id AND b.cid=a.cid 
WHERE a.cid=1 AND 
      a.szbid=0 AND 
      a.id IN(3,4)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've incorporated Thomas' idea of `GROUP BY`, and summing individual quantities, and used your `COALESCE` for `NULL` values :) .

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
SELECT a.id id,a.price price,a.stock stock,
       a.max_per_user max_per_user,a.purchased purchased, 
       COUNT(b.quantity) AS owned 
FROM shop_items a 
          LEFT JOIN shop_inventory b 
                ON b.iid=a.id AND b.cid=a.cid 
WHERE a.cid=1 AND a.szbid=0 AND a.id IN(3,4)
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using `GROUP BY`, slightly modified it using `SUM(COALESCE(b.quantity,0))` instead :) .

Comment: Yeah, SUM(CALESCE()) is probably more inline with what you need. Glad the idea is somewhat helpful. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT a.id id,a.price price,a.stock stock,
       a.max_per_user max_per_user,a.purchased purchased, 
       b.quantity owned 
FROM shop_items a 
LEFT JOIN shop_inventory b ON b.iid=a.id AND b.cid=a.cid 
WHERE a.cid=1 AND a.szbid=0 AND a.id IN(3,4)
```

This will make fields in `b` NULL if they do not match the `ON` clause.

If you want it to be `0`, you can use `IFNULL`

```
SELECT IFNULL(b.quantity, 0) owned
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be where you use Left Join and Group By. If all you need is the count of items from b, that is.

```
SELECT a.id id,a.price price,a.stock stock,
       a.max_per_user max_per_user,a.purchased purchased, 
       COUNT(b.quantity owned) as quantity_owned
FROM shop_items a 
          LEFT JOIN shop_inventory b 
                ON b.iid=a.id AND b.cid=a.cid 
WHERE a.cid=1 AND a.szbid=0 AND a.id IN(3,4)
GROUP BY a.id
```